# Is this a good practice to access a final class with one static method?

Tags: java, javafx, package

I am wondering if this is good practice and a good way to do this.

I am building a JavaFX app via a tutorial. As of now there is no persistance, so i created a final class with one static method, which builds an array of people and returns it so i can populate my app with some information.

In my MainApp class constructor, i call the static method in the other class simply by calling

```
Person[] people = PersonArray.getPeople();
```

the final class looks like such:

```
package com.myubercode.address.model;

import java.time.LocalDate;

/**
 * Created by klown on 4/9/17.
 */
public final class PersonArray {

    public static Person[] getPeople() {
        final Person[] PEOPLE = new Person[5];

        Person p1 = new Person("Hans", "Brix");
        p1.setBirthday(LocalDate.of(1999, 3, 22));
        p1.setStreet("Eldon Court");
        p1.setCity("Denver");
        p1.setPostalCode(80221);
        p1.setState("CO");
        PEOPLE[0] = p1;

        Person p2 = new Person("Aldus", "Eldon");
        p2.setBirthday(LocalDate.of(1976, 2, 02));
        p2.setStreet("Beaudry Dr");
        p2.setCity("Emeryville");
        p2.setPostalCode(98036);
        p2.setState("CA");
        PEOPLE[1] = p2;

        Person p3 = new Person("Juju", "Jones");
        p3.setBirthday(LocalDate.of(1969, 1, 12));
        p3.setStreet("Midland Rd");
        p3.setCity("San Leandro");
        p3.setPostalCode(93063);
        p3.setState("CA");
        PEOPLE[2] = p3;

        Person p4 = new Person("Jazelle", "Jackson");
        p4.setBirthday(LocalDate.of(1991, 5, 26));
        p4.setStreet("Hilary Ct");
        p4.setCity("Beaverton");
        p4.setPostalCode(98018);
        p4.setState("OR");
        PEOPLE[3] = p4;

        Person p5 = new Person("Elton", "Aldus");
        p5.setBirthday(LocalDate.of(1981, 12, 19));
        p5.setStreet("Oleander Circle");
        p5.setCity("Seattle");
        p5.setPostalCode(98107);
        p5.setState("WA");
        PEOPLE[4] = p5;

        return PEOPLE;
    }
}
```

Being that there is no need to instantiate the class and waste memory, is this good practice?
Thanks

Comment: Probably not (though this question is likely too opinion-based for this forum). At some point, you are likely to want to add a real persistence mechanism, for which this acts as a placeholder right now. A static data access object at that point becomes problematic, because you won't be able to control its lifecycle, and so it will be difficult to control things like the creation and release of database resources, etc. So it's probably better now to define a class and make the methods instance methods. Create an instance and pass it to the controllers (or wherever you need it).

Comment: If you write `new PersonArray().getPeople()` it doesn't need to be static.  Then you can do things like override it in different tests.

Answer (score 0):

I will make it an instance and use it in the main app, thanks for your input.